# Upgrade spring project (have google sso) to v4 Jackson JacksonFactory class not found

Tags: spring, jackson, google-sso

I am trying to upgrade my project form spring 3 (using google sso api 1.17.0-rc) to spring 4.1.6. As per [spring migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework#libraries), I have to update the jackson-core-asl-1.9.11 jar to jackson-annotations-2.3.5.jar, jackson-core-2.3.5.jar, jackson-databind-2.3.5.jar and add the same to project classpath. On doing this, i am getting an error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory

As per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148889/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-api-client-json-jsonfactory), i tried to replace the google-api-client jars with 1.20.0 version. but issue still exists.

on searching, i learned that maybe the google api was forcing the application to look for old jackson jar.

Can anybody help me to find a solution?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'securityManager' while setting bean property 'securityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcRealm' while setting bean property 'realms' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcRealm': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.ILoginService com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.impl.MyWebRealm.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcRealm' while setting bean property 'realms' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcRealm': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.ILoginService com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.impl.MyWebRealm.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcRealm': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.ILoginService com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.impl.MyWebRealm.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.ILoginService com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.impl.MyWebRealm.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:44)
    at com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.impl.LoginService.<clinit>(LoginService.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 66 more
10:37:36,816 ERROR ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'securityManager' while setting bean property 'securityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcRealm' while setting bean property 'realms' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcRealm': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.ILoginService com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.impl.MyWebRealm.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcRealm' while setting bean property 'realms' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcRealm': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.ILoginService com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.impl.MyWebRealm.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcRealm': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.ILoginService com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.impl.MyWebRealm.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.ILoginService com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.impl.MyWebRealm.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/wtpwebapps/Fetchinglife-WIP5598/WEB-INF/classes/com/fetchinglife/modules/authentication/service/login/impl/LoginService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:44)
    at com.fetchinglife.modules.authentication.service.login.impl.LoginService.<clinit>(LoginService.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: Jackson moved from `org.codehaus` to `com.fasterxml`

Comment: Add the output of `mvn dependency:tree` and make sure there are no jackson 1 dependencies left, also see which version of the google library supports jackson 2 and not jackson 1 (or how to configure it to use jackson 2). I also suspect you need to add [this dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.api-client%7Cgoogle-api-client-jackson2%7C1.20.0%7Cjar) to have jackson2 integration.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting the question right then, please remove all the jackson dependencies from your repositories and add the following maven dependency inside the pom.xml file.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This will get all the required jar for the jackson with the latest versions. You can check the maven dependencies in the project after the maven has pulled the files.

The second solution can be:

Download all the latest required jar files from the http://mvnrepository.com/ or any other links from the google and place it to the /WEB-INF/library.

After that reference the jar files in the build path of the project.
It will be in the Referenced Libraries in the project.

It works for me, it might work for you too.

Let me know if i have got the question wrong.